# Struct definitions?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct{int x,y;}x;
struct{int x,y;}y;

int main(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Are theses declararations legal on an individual basis these structs? Could both declarations appear as shown in the code or program?

Comment: What did your compiler have to say about it?

Comment: Why not try? it should work!!!

Comment: would be faster to paste it into compiler then post here

Comment: What reason do you have for thinking they wouldn't be legal? Do you think the member names (`int x,y;`) might conflict with the struct object names? Do you think that the member names in the first struct might conflict with the member names in the second? Do you think having two identical struct types would be a problem? We can say "Yes, it's valid", but that knowing why you're asking would help us give more meaningful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wen a structures is declared, it represents a new scope. Therefore, each structure has it own name space. So, nothing wrong with the above snippet.